# iOS10 restrict "Look Up" feature to dictionary alone

Tags: dictionary, iphone, ios

I have just upgraded to iOS10 and found that the "Define" feature (that appears after selecting a word) has been replaced with "Look Up", which now
pulls the suggestions from various sources on internet besides the local dictionary.

Is there a way to restrict this "Look Up" feature to search in local dictionaries alone? I couldn't find any solutions on the internet as of today (14th Sep16).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The instructions are in the "About Lookup & Privacy" that you read before using it for the first time... I can't figure out how you could get to see that a second time, fortunately I grabbed a screenshot while I was there.

Settings > General > Spotlight Search - disable Suggestions, for Search &/or Look up.

[image]